# Avoiding code repetition with discriminated unions

Tags: typescript, overloading, dry

Say I have this function

```
async function getTracksOrAlbums(
  tracksOrAlbums: {tracks: Track[]} | {albums: Album[]},
  notFound: NotFound,
): Promise<GetTracksOrAlbums> {
  if ('albums' in tracksOrAlbums) {
    const albumsResponse = await getManyAlbums(tracksOrAlbums.albums)

    const result = albumsResponse.filter((item, i): item is AlbumResponse => {
      return filterErrors(() => {
        notFound.total++
        notFound.data.push(tracksOrAlbums.albums[i])
      }, item)
    })
    return {
      data: result,
      report: {found: result.length, notFound},
    }
  }

  const tracksResponse = await getManyTracks(tracksOrAlbums.tracks)
  const result = tracksResponse.filter((item, i): item is TrackResponse => {
    return filterErrors(() => {
      notFound.total++
      notFound.data.push(tracksOrAlbums.tracks[i])
    }, item)
  })

  return {
    data: result,
    report: {found: result.length, notFound},
  }
}
```

I want to **abstract** the following part into a separate function:

```
const albumsResponse = await getManyAlbums(tracksOrAlbums.albums)
const result = albumsResponse.filter((item, i): item is AlbumResponse => {
  return filterErrors(() => {
    notFound.total++
    notFound.data.push(tracksOrAlbums.albums[i])
  }, item)
})
```

In almost ***pseudo-code*** I would like to do something in the lines of:

```
async function filterTracksOrAlbums<T extends Track | Album>(
  tracksOrAlbums: Array<T>,
  notFound: NotFound,
) {
  const searchRes = await getManyTracks(tracksOrAlbums) // or await getManyAlbums(tracksOrAlbums)
  const result = searchRes.filter(
    // I don't really know how to define here a generic type guard
    (item, i): item is T => {
      //
      return filterErrors(() => {
        notFound.total++
        notFound.data.push(tracksOrAlbums[i])
      }, item)
    },
  )
  return result
}
```

I would also like to express the **relation** between inputs:

```
(Track | Album)[]
```

and outputs:

```
(TrackResponse | AlbumResponse)[]
```

without incurring into repetition because if I were to add another case for say **playlists** or **user** **data**,
I would have to rewrite every time the `filter` callback and it's correspondent **type
guard** to match a possible `PlaylistResponse` and `UserResponse`

Is there a way to encapsulate this code without incurring in such repetition? I started using
**function overloads** but made the code unnecessarily complicated.

---

`getManyAlbums` and `getManyTracks` are functions that perform requests to an API which could be mocked as:

```
function getManyAlbums(
  albums: Album[],
): Promise<(AlbumResponse | ErrorResponse)[]> {
  return Promise.resolve([
    {ok: false, message: 'error message'},
    {ok: true, data: {id: '1', name: 'bar', artist: 'foo'}},
  ])
}

function getManyTracks(
  tracks: Track[],
): Promise<(TrackResponse | ErrorResponse)[]> {
  return Promise.resolve([
    {ok: true, data: {id: '1', name: 'bar', artist: 'foo', isrc: 'baz'}},
    {ok: false, message: 'error message'},
  ])
}
```

and these are the relevant **type declarations**:

```
type Track = {artist: string; song: string}
type Album = {artist: string; album: string}

type TrackResponse = {
  ok: true
  data: {id: string; name: string; artist: string; isrc: string}
}
type AlbumResponse = {
  ok: true
  data: {id: string; name: string; artist: string}
}

type ErrorResponse = {ok: false; message: string}

type NotFound = {total: number; data: unknown[]}
type GetReturnType<T> = {
  data: T
  report: {found: number; notFound: NotFound}
}

type GetTracks = GetReturnType<TrackResponse[]>
type GetAlbums = GetReturnType<AlbumResponse[]>
type GetTracksOrAlbums = GetTracks | GetAlbums
```

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link)](https://tsplay.dev/WkvoPm), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing (so no undeclared or undefined types or values).  This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Comment: I tried to simplify it and added the code needed to run it, but I think it's quite lengthy though. I hope it'd be clearer this time.

Comment: Yeah, there's quite a lot going on there; could you try to pare it down so that it still shows the issue of duplication while not including all the functionality?  It's probably true that unless you can come up with a truly *generic* abstraction, you'll end up needing to do a lot of extra type manipulation (overloads or assertions or helper functions) to get it to work.

Comment: So, you could do something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mMRa1W), where your union is actually a discriminated union with a discriminant property (`type` in this example) and then write generic functions operating on an input/output type map.  But I don't know if it's worth it to you.  If so I could maybe write up an answer, but I would definitely prefer to do so on a more minimal example.  Good luck!

Comment: Ok, I tried your suggestion and I liked it! I ended up with the code that I tagged here: 
[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/w8Ab4N)

And I also got rid of the function overload after realizing it was unnecessary. But since I'm rather new to TypeScript I'm not completely sure

Comment: So, should I write up an answer, then?  Or is there anything missing?

Comment: Well it's up to you, but I think it might be nice for the community if you could elaborate a little bit about the correlation between types and why is it kind of an unsolved problem right now in Typescript. Either way, if you decide to answer it I would accept it as a solution since it's what I'm using right now in my code. Thanks a lot, by the way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll find it easier to abstract common functionality into a single function if the data structures you manipulate are as similar as possible.  Instead of using different *keys* to distinguish whether something is related to an `Album` or a `Track`, you should probably use different *values* to do this.

For example, the input-output mapping looks something like this:

```
// Input types
interface TrackInput { artist: string; song: string }
interface AlbumInput { artist: string; album: string }

// Output Types
interface TrackOutput { id: string; name: string; artist: string; isrc: string }
interface AlbumOutput { id: string; name: string; artist: string }

interface DataIO {
  albums: { input: AlbumInput, output: AlbumOutput },
  tracks: { input: TrackInput, output: TrackOutput }
}
```

The `DataIO` type is just meant to let the compiler keep track of which input goes with which output.  If we can represent your functionality in terms of these types alone, then we have a chance to use `DataIO` to do so [generically](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).

---

We can define outputs like this:

```
interface Response<T> { ok: true, data: T }
interface ErrorResponse { ok: false; message: string }
type ResponseOrError<T> = (Response<T> | ErrorResponse)[]
```

And for the inputs, we can split the original `{albums: AlbumInput[]}` or `{tracks: TrackInput[]}` into two parameters: a `type` parameter `"albums"` or `"tracks"`, and a `searchData` parameter of either `AlbumInput[]` or `TrackInput[]`, depending on `type`.

That will look like:

```
declare function getManyThings<K extends keyof DataIO>(
  type: K,
  searchData: Array<DataIO[K]['input']>
): Promise<ResponseOrError<DataIO[K]['output']>>;
```

That's a generic function where `K` is the type of `type`, and we're using [indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) to give the right type to `searchData`.

Implementing that in terms of the existing functions will require some [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) or the like, since the compiler can't really follow that the return value will actually match the declared return type.  It can see that `type` is a particular value, but this doesn't have any effect on `K`.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014) for an issue requesting support for such a feature.  Anyway, it could be like this:

```
function getManyThings<K extends keyof DataIO>(
  type: K,
  searchData: Array<DataIO[K]['input']>
): Promise<ResponseOrError<DataIO[K]['output']>> {
  return type === "albums" ? 
    getManyAlbums(searchData as AlbumInput[]) : 
    getManyTracks(searchData as TrackInput[]);
}
```

And then you can write your `filterTracksOrAlbums` like this without any additional problems:

```
async function filterTracksOrAlbums<K extends keyof DataIO>(
  type: K,
  tracksOrAlbums: Array<DataIO[K]['input']>,
  notFound: NotFound,
) {
  const searchRes = await getManyThings(type, tracksOrAlbums);

  const result = searchRes.filter(
    (item, i): item is Response<DataIO[K]['output']> => {
      return filterErrors(() => {
        notFound.total++
        notFound.data.push(tracksOrAlbums[i])
      }, item)
    },
  )
  return result
}
```

Note that since `filterTracksOrAlbums()` is also generic in `K`, the `type` of the data to search for, we can represent the [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) of the filter code generically as `item is Response<DataIO[K]['output']>`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApFSDeAoJTSVgWRXhABsAvTLGnXJAegaQElgYBXAFyS4E8Y0OrgCWwLhABOAMyJIAKpIQBrNpx4YkISVxFQuALiT7JYgOYBuYwHtgZoyfNIAvsKRiJMuQEEyAIw4wNW5MLR09Q2MuUzsrcgCwB2inVzcPKVlEBSV4ZQB5bnVQkQATJJjLPHAIcvM48P1a2PcoSXgmsxc08Qyff0CCriLNUo6rfBqoivrdRqmUmnpGZkGi+QEIRfp0ryyAERAuEBY86iXceMCoIxH2biNfBOCuABoka0L7pEeBz55nF5uXDRFTXYp3SKKFTPN4fIZfKG5VYhVxLVJLHaZZAAJWgMFsUAgAB55AA+ULWZRGaIcCBvEqHEBGeRdDE9XbIACikkk1kkuNgBOQmkpRlkZEJVgIUBAZkmjjsrPo-EESAF+OAhLykm5vMkJPJAF4kAAKdVCg1IAA+SF1fPNmogAEoANoAXS2uCYSxVyERyigDq1Op5fKQxpN-qDyBtdv5eKFro9S29yo2336YEDCcd2rj4dNPzA0etttD8cFjqTnuWaogXA4kmAvA2UDcvqQADlrFwAGIfYAlAuaLg98hGYCBPxSKwMo5GDjAZTAawAd2A7q6bmki-gulsSDlXAAsiBgHx-VATSDcmD-c93U6zud4ASeDeA9GjNG8+WSTl8j+I0kBdIF6Gwc5zlFXhJFpQFIKWOcmWKMokAAcgARjQt4JiMNDOxAEQwBAbCwlmSI0JQawAAtmwAYWsMgQWACBSL0No8JAKASgAWiwlx4IQgEwNwCCENwaCaTpET6CQm4ZIxVC0IAJmwhT6Fw9C6MkPh9HIJAAGURDICBgEQNTxKWbRyLwujqJEXIkAYyQIBIwTLJaDj0K43jVPcoT-LRQLwPeKkkHFQk3mlWVJgAIgYjgyBKYA0J4aQxCHD90IADy4tDwt5MBvO4kAQFXKA0NigSwI9MCXIbJskAABUKvQIAAOhcqBGIANwga8AOzStCSdNx0XoHczP3Zsj1Pc8iyvS4sweTMHzdJ8xKWV9NR4Jaho1QlvxzYM4yJItkS4YDQPEkUwqk+lGRudwlKwnDqjwgBpRj6NsRAdFI6yIk+iARC4ajUG0equHy5xqpu9TJNg6SPLklC8L8qpIDw3EGubeRrCQfsXL6yQAYaCi7Ic5QnL5VyYeC3BhMg2rIPqxtmxa6wwDazroF6-q9ujUa0Rrb0AAkIDIQRJHC3dpvCsN0qYqQnDhMs9SQPI-AAKwgPc2yWSa9xEA8lc8OMr2kYAjBNJ9DXJHrrFKN5QYgRItHPJ0jD8axGNc5tNvobb9BaU8uHgcHjVdsB2spJAADJ4-cCQY9HI4yATpPo-atP9PJAAGGtRGkU0AEI9DDiONpkq3bbA8aljZxqK8OCOxprI35dms8L3suwoCJD6kAgbKJEHKAkGUCA+GsEuDiOE5SRNMDfSMD7gsJbQI-n5DvB5EA+CJHeThdD63RdNCxHUNC3VJNwvea1rCSJH8Qz1I-GRPs+L7ha-b-JQOXpmAzw4EgVcxkM4sQgEObqkAtBQEJOEAkSBqJSGQNOUgHBCSHnrHNPgC0PZDm7ueS8YRkArh4HKFiph4BgW9GeTKqCXJoQniuQ8vshyrgPrwAmJQCavh5JLQ4JtNQoLQW8QkyBqJcCGNcJgZhQbUQ4H4dqr4wAMG5vAXk3VpBcAYOsQQBktEiBgHovQUBaRQAYAAZnzgAVgABwYTqvWdmLZVSGk8UgWKe0qoAH4cEnh7gtE0m82jUR3vAjMTwISPiQEYYhF5BqhNcuEyJXFsjQlietdubguJ8DMrLKaIjwrGU8JebUC1B7D1HqZEoE8p4zznp-PIS8V4bDXsFD8UBKmZjBHvJQh9j55FPufS+EIb6kmChQ-si5ULdj7AOEo-lq6QWDjwMJEcBQFjKoRShuCe7yD7mYK8vo3jdN6QkKAToLBFyQOspAXVEo8GNJs6iAp2pmykMvcSJpo4uwftHFodZhrEmGaMn+fxJnhgAepJuzYvlvz5FeW2MLnweRmUsnOY4yAAGpcXqVwJiuZ7UkLtU4FAaiA1QSXKuC6EQOSPIAmTm7YWAUwJssbq4xqTymK5K2K4ZwQA)